# Text input in Rails Article-like site

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm building a rails site that will display different articles, where a publisher can go in and copy/paste a word doc (or edit it on a page).  How would I have a textbox treat the formatting of the document that they would store?  I know how to do normal text input and store in a database model, but how does rails treat formatting (bold, font size, colors, indentations of an individually stored article) and store that in the database?  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways you can store the text. One way would be for the editor to generate HTML files (or html.erb ones) which would then be shown to visitors of the website. The page would then be styled based on relevant CSS.

You can also use ready-made blogging solutions, such as [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) or [Typo](https://github.com/fdv/typo).

Comment: I've looked at Typo before, the problem is that it seems to handle much of the database ( the models and storing them ?).  I would want to define my own model called "Article" (or w/e the name is) and have one field represent the article.  Then when i want to display it, be able to show the formatting and everything (including an update availability).  Does Typo save as html docs as well as css?  I haven't looked THAT much into it.  Thanks